# React.js sticky nav not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.js. I'm trying to get the left nav to stick on scroll. For some reason the code below is causing the following error when I scroll:

Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Any help would be great! thanks

```
class Sticky extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scrollingLock: false
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll() {

  if (window.scrollY > 100) {
    console.log("should lock");
    this.setState({
      scrollingLock: true
    });
  } else if (window.scrollY < 100) {
    console.log("not locked" );
    this.setState({
      scrollingLock: false
    });
  }

}

render() {

    return (
            <div style={{ width: "100%", position: this.state.scrollingLock ? "fixed" : "relative"}}>
                    {this.props.children}
            </div>
          )
            }
   }

export default Sticky;
```

Comment: Have you tried to bind _handleScroll_ method?

Answer (score 10):

This code should work for you.

```
class Sticky extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scrollingLock: false
    };
    // example how to bind object in React ES6
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

handleScroll() {

  if (window.scrollY > 100) {
    console.log("should lock");
    this.setState({
      scrollingLock: true
    });
  } else if (window.scrollY < 100) {
    console.log("not locked" );
    this.setState({
      scrollingLock: false
    });
  }

}

render() {

    return (
            <div style={{ width: "100%", position: this.state.scrollingLock ? "fixed" : "relative"}}>
                    {this.props.children}
            </div>
          )
            }
   }

 React.render(<Sticky/> , document.body)
```

Also [here](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html) is a good article around binding in ES6 React Code.

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should put the method and the instance into one function using [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).
I recommend you to save bound function as a property like this:

```
class Sticky extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
    this._handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this._handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this._handleScroll);
  }
  ..
}
```

[React component doesn't auto bind with ES6 class.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding) So you manually bind the instance and its methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I used `react-sticky` which you can find [here](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky). It's very simple to install, and if you want to see some live code for reference, you can see that [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEyWZo). Of course that's adding another dependency, but it also took me 10 minutes to get it running. Good luck!